# How to perform pandas drop_duplicates based on index column

Tags: datetime, pandas, duplicates, time-series

I am banging my head against the wall when trying to perform a drop duplicate for time series, base on the value of a datetime index.

My function is the following:

```
def csv_import_merge_T(f):
    dfsT = [pd.read_csv(fp,  index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, names=['datetime','temp','rh'], header=0) for fp in files] 
    dfT = pd.concat(dfsT)
    #print dfT.head(); print dfT.index; print dfT.dtypes
    dfT.drop_duplicates(subset=index, inplace=True)
    dfT.resample('H').bfill()
    return dfT
```

which is called by:

```
inputcsvT = ['./input_csv/A08_KI_T*.csv']
for csvnameT in inputcsvT:
    files = glob.glob(csvnameT)
    print ('___'); print (files)
    t = csv_import_merge_T(files)
    print csvT
```

I receive the error

```
NameError: global name 'index' is not defined
```

what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**
The issue appear to arise when csv input files (which are to be concatenated) are overlapped.

`inputcsvT = ['./input_csv/A08_KI_T*.csv']` gets files
**A08_KI_T5**
28/05/2015 17:00,22.973,24.021
...
08/10/2015 13:30,24.368,45.974

**A08_KI_T6**
08/10/2015 14:00,24.779,41.526
...
10/02/2016 17:00,22.326,41.83

and it runs correctly, whereas:
`inputcsvT = ['./input_csv/A08_LR_T*.csv']` gathers
**A08_LR_T5**
28/05/2015 17:00,22.493,25.62
...
08/10/2015 13:30,24.296,44.596
**A08_LR_T6**
28/05/2015 17:00,22.493,25.62
...
10/02/2016 17:15,21.991,38.45
which leads to an error.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to achieve here? for instance if you have duplicates are you wanting to trim the df of the duplicates? You could call `reset_index` and the call `drop_duplicates` passing in the `index` column name and this will remove the duplicates

Comment: unfortunately if I do that I get the error:
`KeyError"DatetimeIndex(...
...dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'datetime', length=50276, freq=None) not in index"`

Comment: does my suggestion below work? You may need to determine the index name, by default it's 'index' but you may need to get the name first

Comment: Can you try `dfT[~dfT.index.duplicated()]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC you can call `reset_index` and then `drop_duplicates` and then `set_index` again:

```
In [304]:
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(5,3), index=list('aabcd'))
df

Out[304]:
          0         1         2
a  0.918546 -0.621496 -0.210479
a -1.154838 -2.282168 -0.060182
b  2.512519 -0.771701 -0.328421
c -0.583990 -0.460282  1.294791
d -1.018002  0.826218  0.110252

In [308]:
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('index').set_index('index')

Out[308]:
              0         1         2
index                              
a      0.918546 -0.621496 -0.210479
b      2.512519 -0.771701 -0.328421
c     -0.583990 -0.460282  1.294791
d     -1.018002  0.826218  0.110252
```

**EDIT**

Actually there is a simpler method is to call `duplicated` on the index and invert it:

```
In [309]:
df[~df.index.duplicated()]

Out[308]:
              0         1         2
index                              
a      0.918546 -0.621496 -0.210479
b      2.512519 -0.771701 -0.328421
c     -0.583990 -0.460282  1.294791
d     -1.018002  0.826218  0.110252
```

Comment: I have tried
`df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('index').set_index('index')` and received the error
`"ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit"`

Comment: You failed to answer my last comment or whether `df[~df.index.duplicated()]` worked for you

Comment: EdChum, thanks for that.
I did try `dfT[~dfT.index.duplicated()]` and it returned the same error as above

Comment: Then you've got some fundamental issue with your dfs which I can't reproduce as my small example shows this should work, in order to progress this you need to post representative sample data or a link to your actual data

Comment: I have updated my question to include sample data, possibly explaining why the error happens.

Comment: Are you able to sort the index after concat? My code should still work though

Comment: I can get it to work by using: `dfT_clean = dfT.reset_index().drop_duplicates('datetime').set_index('datetime')`

Comment: Glad you could sort it out

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Would you be able to advise on a follow up query (same chunk of code but different function)?

Comment: Normal practice is to ask a new question unless the query is minor and related, what is the new function?

Comment: You are right.
with ref. to the above function: `def csv_import_merge_**T**(f)`
I have created a similar one called `def csv_import_merge_**R**(f)`.
Using an example - A08 (unit) KI(room): after import_merge A08_KI_T5 and T6, I want to import_merge A08_KI_R5,R6 **then** subtract A08_KI_R(merged and time-resampled) from A08_KI_T(merged and time-resampled).

The code is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qffm35fn8dv3awt/Task1_v8.py?dl=0

Comment: subtraction should just work so long as index values and column names agree on lhs and rhs, have you tried this?

Comment: This recursives and sub-recursives do the job. However the subtraction needs to happen only when csvnameR[12:20] = csvnameT[12:20], that is when csvR = csvT.
A08_KI_R needs to be subtracted from A08_KI_T and not from, say, A08_LR_T

http://pastie.org/private/01tewfrlmdqoufhhpuqhq

Comment: Sorry is this a column name you're trying to match on? so `df[df['col_name'].str.contains('some_string')]`

Comment: not a column name, but rather the name of the two variables which are looping - csvR and csvT as from my code above

Comment: I think you need to post a new question as it's unclear to me, you should include sample data, your code and what the desired output should be, please post code rather than describe your output as it's a little unclear to me what you're trying to achieve

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.
I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696943/recursive-csv-import-functions